# Why difference in behavior while populating collection containing elements of type <? extends T>?

Tags: java, generics, jls

In the following code snippet it gives compilation error on line 2 but it doesn't on line 3.

```
List<? extends Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // line 1
list1.add("123"); // line 2

List<? extends Object> list2 = Arrays.asList("123", new Integer(12)); // line 3
```

If language designers have decided, not to allow to add elements into collection of element type `<? extends T>` then it should apply to line 3 too.

What could be the reason for this difference?

Please clarify.

Comment: You are not adding to list2 once it is initialized

Comment: Related: [What is PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: Change code to `List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();`, then add whatever you like.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `add(?)` on a `List<?>`.

Since the compiler doesn't know what the `?` is, there is no possible value (except `null`) that you can pass that is guaranteed to be legal for every possible `?`.

Your second example doesn't call any method that takes a `?` as a parameter, so it isn't unsafe.